# EXTENDS/MIXIN - how access DATA() and change MERGE way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

- **A WAY TO ACCESS DATA FROM ORIGINAL/BASE COMPONENT IN EXTENDED COMPONENT DATA()**
- **A WAY TO MERGE IN VUE 3 LIKE VUE 2**

If are you looking for a way to extends/mixins your code to add some functionality to your component(tag) organizing then, codding less and creating a beautiful clean legible vue structure but maybe you need to know the differences between vue 2 and 3 and helping-us to find some these anwers

## EXEMPLE CODE

*(Ex: Caller)*

```
<!-- APP.VUE -->
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h2>Original/base 'tag': <original message="Test String" /></h2>
    <hr>
    <h2>EXTENDED 'tag': <EXTENDoriginal message="Have this too" extra="THIS OTHER PROP" /></h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseComponent from "./components/BaseComponent.vue"
import ExtendedComponent from "./components/ExtendedComponent.vue"

export default {
    components: {
        original: BaseComponent,
        EXTENDoriginal: ExtendedComponent,
    }
}
</script>
```

*(Ex: Original/Base component)*

```
<!-- BaseComponent.vue = Option API Component -->
<template>
  <div style="color:red;">
    <div>Original component: {{ message }}</div>
    <div>{{ user }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "original",

    props: {
        message: {
          type: String, required: false
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            primitive: 1,
            user: {
                name: 'Jack', id: 1111
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ORIGINAL_FUNCTION(val) {
            alert(val)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*(Ex: Extended component from Original/Base)*

```
<!-- ExtendedComponent.vue = Option API Component EXTENDED -->
<template>
  <div style="color:blue;">
    <div>EXTENDED component: <u>{{ message }}</u></div>
    <div>plus <u>{{ extra }}</u></div>
    <div>user: {{ user }}</div>
    <h4 @click="exampleFuncExtended">Click here to call "original" function from "local" function</h4>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Original from "./BaseComponent.vue"

export default {
    name: "EXTENDoriginal",

    extends: Original,

    props: {
        extra: {
          type: String, required: false
        }
    },
    data() {
        let primitiveExtended = this.primitive + 99

        return {
            primitiveExtended,
            user: {
                id: 9999
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        exampleFuncExtended() {
            alert(this.primitive + '(ok) -- ' + this.primitiveExtended + ' (does not work)')
            this.ORIGINAL_FUNCTION("hello it's me you're looking for - A call to original Sample")
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## MUST KNOW

VUE 2.5.2 will return ( try/test https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-extends-example-q5rcpk )

```
Original/base 'tag':
Original component: Test String
{ "name": "Jack", "id": 1111 }
------------------------------------
EXTENDED 'tag':
EXTENDED component: Have this too
plus THIS OTHER PROP and NaN
user: { "id": 9999, "name": "Jack" } <------ VUE 2 MERGE
```

VUE 3.0.2 will return ( try/test https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-extends-example-o50lh1 )

```
Original/base 'tag':
Original component: Test String
{ "name": "Jack", "id": 1111 }
------------------------------------
EXTENDED 'tag':
EXTENDED component: Have this too
plus THIS OTHER PROP and NaN
user: { "id": 9999 }                 <------ VUE 3 MERGE
```

1 - you can find some information about this at https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/data-option.html and a mention "Migration build flag: OPTIONS_DATA_FN" but I'm looking for a way to merge like VUE 2 just into one simple component/page not all project

2 - the "NaN" it's a start to ask: Is there a way to read data from original/base component into data() section of extended component? Because they are accessible in  and methods: like example code above do